# How to Add VAT or Business number on .PDF invoice?

Tags: magento-1.7

How to add a Business Number or VAT number on .PDF invoice that is generated in Magento?

Answer (score 2):

One of the ways to alter **INVOICE PDF** file is by going to **System >>  Configuration >> SALES >> Sales** and adding necessary information to the Address field in the **Invoice and Package slip design** section.

In my case, its a business number, it will show in the top right corner on the PDF invoice.

No coding alteration required. Does the trick.